# How to set the width of a `div` with fixed positioning to the width of a sibling with static positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the width of the `.bottom-nav` the same as all the sibling divs such as `.stick`, `.x` and `.zindex` but so far nothing has worked and I'm getting a little bit confused, please take it easy on me  as I've only been coding for a week.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blah {
  border: 5px dashed black;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.divdiv {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.margin {
  background-color: plum;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  text-align: center;
}

.x {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: static;
}

.gra {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  position: static;
}

.stick,
.zindex {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  height: 2000px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.gr,
.grow {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.gr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
}

.grow {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  border: 6px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.zindex {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gr1,
.gr2,
.gr3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px grey;
}

.gr1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.gr2 {
  background-color: crimson;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.gr3 {
  background-color: bisque;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 75px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.bottom-nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  text-align: center;
}

.float,
.empty {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

.left,
.right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 25px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Practice</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="blah">
    <div class="divdiv"></div>
  </div>

  <p class="margin">H</p>

  <div class="x">
    <div class="gra"></div>
    <div class="gra"></div>
    <div class="gra"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="stick">
    <div class="gr"></div>
    <div class="grow"></div>
    <div class="gr"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="zindex">
    <div class="gr1"></div>
    <div class="gr2"></div>
    <div class="gr3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="float">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="empty"></div>

  <div class="bottom-nav">

  </div>
</body>
</html
```

Tried setting the width to 100% but it takes the full width of the html, set it to inherit the width of the body but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The following additions seem to fix your issue:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bottom-nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); 
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I changed the color of `bottom-nav` for better clarity.

The `margin-right: auto` is responsible for centering bottom-nav horizontally. `width: calc(100% - 40px);` calculates the width of the nav. We are subtracting 40px from the full width to take into account the margins (20 px on each side).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.blah {
  border: 5px dashed black;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.divdiv {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.margin {
  background-color: plum;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  text-align: center;
}

.x {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: static;
}

.gra {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  position: static;
}

.stick,
.zindex {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  height: 2000px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.gr,
.grow {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.gr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
}

.grow {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  border: 6px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.zindex {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gr1,
.gr2,
.gr3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px grey;
}

.gr1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.gr2 {
  background-color: crimson;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.gr3 {
  background-color: bisque;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 75px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.bottom-nav {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 4;
  text-align: center;
}

.float,
.empty {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

.left,
.right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 25px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="blah">
    <div class="divdiv"></div>
  </div>

  <p class="margin">H</p>

  <div class="x">
    <div class="gra"></div>
    <div class="gra"></div>
    <div class="gra"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="stick">
    <div class="gr"></div>
    <div class="grow"></div>
    <div class="gr"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="zindex">
    <div class="gr1"></div>
    <div class="gr2"></div>
    <div class="gr3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="float">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="empty"></div>

  <div class="bottom-nav">
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Hey bunny this is amazing, it resizes the way I want when I adjust the screen size but I just wanted to know quickly, how'd you get 80px if I only set the left and right margins to 20 each for all elements on the page?

Comment: the `html` page also had some margin to it. I modified my answer to reset the html and make the answer clearer.

Comment: also I don't recommend that you apply margins and paddings in the `*` selector because it will apply these attributes to ALL elements including the ones nested inside the nav bar. You will have to remember to overwrite the padding and margin every time you write the css of a new element.